# php security with url?

Tags: php, url

When I accessed my php webpage then its url looks **http://hostname/mydir/index.php**

but I want to secure my web address and it should be look like **http://hostname/virtual_dir1/virtual_dir2/mydir** 

Please help me how  can I secure my web page url.


Thanks,

Comment: How does that "secure" your web address?

Comment: I think you should be using htaccess for that..

Comment: @Sudhir: But I don't know what are the directives for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it with a rewrite rule in your .htaccess :
Ex :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^virtual_dir1/virtual_dir2/mydir /mydir/index.php
```

For more informations about redirection from .htaccess, look here.
http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with security, it only is for aesthetics. You need to look at mod_rewrite (assuming you're using Apache) and using RewriteRule in .htaccess. Take a look here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html